# $\displaystyle 3^x+4^x=5^x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that the equation $\displaystyle 3^x+4^x=5^x$ has exactly one root

I proved it graphically but I am in need of an analytic solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$3^x+4^x=5^x\iff\left(\frac35\right)^x+\left(\frac45\right)^x=1$. Since the exponential function on the left hand side is strictly decreasing, it follows that the equation, were it to ever be true for a certain *x*, then that *x* is unique. And it is indeed true for $x=2$, making it its only solution.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Observe that $\frac35,\frac45<1,$

So, $$\left(\frac35\right)^m+\left(\frac45\right)^m<\left(\frac35\right)^2+\left(\frac45\right)^2=1  \text{  for }m>2$$

and $$\left(\frac35\right)^m+\left(\frac45\right)^m>\left(\frac35\right)^2+\left(\frac45\right)^2=1 \text{  for }m<2$$

This can be generalized for any  [Pythagorean triple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)

Answer (score 4):

A hint: Use that
$$x\mapsto\left({3\over5}\right)^x+\left({4\over5}\right)^x=e^{-\log\!{5\over3}\>x}+e^{-\log\!{5\over4}\>x}$$
is strictly decreasing on ${\mathbb R}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that $f(x) = 3^x+4^x-5^x$ has a zero on some interval.  The use Rolle's theorem to show you can't have more than one zero.

Comment: I.V.T proves there is a zero $x=a$ between 1 and 3. Now I assume there is a zero at $x=b$. So that there is a $x=d$ between a and b such that $f'(d)=0$. How do I show now that there is no value which can satisfy this?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
write 5^x=(4+1)^x and use binomial expansion

then simplify

it seems to have answer  only for x=2

Comment: Do you use usual binomial coefficients or something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol ? Just curious.

Comment: This rules out all non-negative integer solutions $x\ne2.$ What about other possible solutions?

Comment: you are right . i prove it for x=2,3,4,5...  integers

Comment: by numerical method x=2.564 is another answer I think