# Solving this Exponential Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is the equation that I need help with. The fact that there is that extra $1$ is throwing me off. If you move the $4^x$ term over and take the $\log$ of both sides, then you have a $\log$ with a polynomial inside.

$$5^x - 4^x = 1$$

Comment: I know this is super embarrassing. I just completed BC Calc and I haven't done exponents/logs in such a long time.

Comment: Do you only want real solutions?  Have you discounted the trivial $x=1$, or are you including it in your solution set?

Comment: Your sense that it's hard to solve this with algebra is correct: For example, if you were solving $5^x-4^x=2$, then you'd only be able to solve numerically.

Comment: Perhaps you can prove that there is only one solution? You already know that $x = 1$ is that solution.

Comment: I only want real solutions, and I am including x=1.

Comment: Do you know Rolle's Theorem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem
I know the question is tagged "algebra-precalculus" but if you know one or two basic things about derivatives you can prove that there is only one solution: $x = 1$

Answer (score 3):

As a way to prove that this equation has only a single solution among the real numbers, consider the following transformation:

$$5^x-4^x=1\iff 1=\left(\frac 15\right)^x+\left(\frac 45\right)^x$$

Now it is plain that the RHS is a strictly-positive, strictly-decreasing function as compared with the LHS constant.  A numeric method will easily find the solution for $x$ in this case, but I do not know of any algebraic method to solve this type of formula.

Also, note [my answer to this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767498/how-to-solve-for-a-variable-that-is-only-in-exponents/767539#767539), where I find that it is possible to rewrite the equation in pseudo-polynomial form, with the exception that at least one exponent is not rational.

Answer (score 0):

The function $y(x)=5^x-4^x$ is negative if $x<0$ . So $x<0$ is excluded. For $x>0$  the function is strictly increasing from $0$ to $\infty$. So, there is only one value of $x$ so that $y=1$.

Obviously this value is $x=1$ because  $y(1)=5^1-4^1=1$